# Use ternary operator to show specific items from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, conditional-operator, use-state

I'm unable to show conditional output with the ternary operator. I want to pass a value to a function and show only related info from the state. My code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Tasks({taskId, index}){

 {task.parentId == taskId : }       //Unable to code this.

  return(       //show only tasks where parentId == taskId
         <div>
           <div> {task.title} </div>
           <div> {task.body} </div>
         </div>
        )
}

function App(){

    const[tasks, setTasks] = useState([
        {
            taskId: 1,
            title: 'Task1',
            body: 'This is the body of the task1',
            isComplete: false,
            parentId: 0
        },
        {
            taskId: 2,
            title: 'Task2',
            body: 'This is the body of the task2',
            isComplete: false,
            parentId: 1
        },      
        {
            taskId: 3,
            title: 'Task3',
            body: 'This is the body of the task3',
            isComplete: false,
            parentId: 1
        },
        {
            taskId: 4,
            title: 'Task4',
            body: 'This is the body of the task4',
            isComplete: false,
            parentId: 3
        }
    ])

    return(
            <div style={{marginLeft: 20}}>
                <h1>ToDo</h1>

                {tasks.map((task, index)=>
                    <Tasks 
                        taskId=1
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        )
}

export default App;
```

So, I want to only show the tasks that have the `parentId` as 1. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the least modification to the code, you can return an empty fragment or null:

```
function Tasks({ task }) {
    return task.parentId == task.taskId
        ? (
            <div>
                <div> {task.title} </div>
                <div> {task.body} </div>
            </div>
        )
        : null;
}
```

(make sure to use `parentId`, not `pasrentId`, and `task.taskId`, not `taskId` - you aren't passing `task` as a prop currently, so change the code to do so: `<Tasks task={task} />`)

But I think it'd make more sense to use `.filter` in the caller:

```
return (
    <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
        <h1>ToDo</h1>
        {tasks
            .filter(task => task.parentId === task.taskId)
            .map(task => <Task task={task} />)
        }
    </div>
)
```

(since `Tasks` renders a single task, consider calling it `Task` instead of `Tasks`)

Comment: I used `.filter(task => task.parentId == 1)` and it works. Now need to pull that value from the state as well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to render only those tasks with the specified `id`, you may not have to use the ternary operator.

```js
function renderTasks(id) {
  return tasks
    .filter(({ taskId }) => taskId == id)
    .map(({ title, body }) => (
      <div>
        <div> {title} </div>
        <div> {body} </div>
      </div>
    ));
}
```